# Best way to sort by AVG and COUNT in MySql

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I am working on a simple rating system, as I asked  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357075/advanced-rating-system-mysql-database-optimization)

The data is semi-large (100k records), I have a rate table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rates` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `imageid` (`imageid`)
)
```

It stores the rates of users for each image. as you can see I have just a key for this table (imageid) that is used for OUTER JOIN in another query...

But in this simple query without any JOIN I have problem too:

```
SELECT r.imageid,COUNT(r.id) as cnt,AVG(r.rate) AS arate,MAX(r.sdate) as lastdate  FROM rates r  GROUP BY r.imageid 
ORDER BY
arate DESC, cnt DESC,lastdate DESC
```

The Explain says that the query is **Using temporary; Using filesort.** In my large database it is problem and this problem spreads to my main JOIN query.

Is there any way to get top Average of fields without sorting? (It sorts by AVG and cannot use index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion - use in table images - fields sum_rates and count_rates and by every rate - add rate to sum_rates and add +1 to count_rates.

And if you need to get average rate, you can this select

```
select (sum_rates / count_rates)
from images
```

This query must be work much rather.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was going to do this, but In my system I need Top of day,week,month....! In another word I want to get the top average in different days. Your solution just gives the total average from the beginning!

Comment: When you want use finite count of top - you can use additional temporary tables and count this top one time (through) cron in a day (6 hours, 1 hour etc).

Unfortunately Indexes don't support in aggregate functions like AVG.

Answer (score 2):

The common optimization for various statistics - is precalculation.

It's very rare when you need to have 100% actual averages. So just precalculate it to another table and get the results instantly.

The actual state may be maintained by triggers or by schedule.

Comment: @MscEliot: you create separated table, calculate all the `COUNT`, `AVG` etc and persist there. After that you work with precalculated data. And refresh it as often as it is required